# PowerPoint VBA code throws 'Shape Type Mismatch' error

Tags: vba, shapes, powerpoint, type-mismatch

Hoping you can help. Below is a quick sub that *should* create a new powerpoint shape based on the shape sent to the procedure x many times. I'm getting a Type Mismatch error the second time through when I try to duplicate the original shape.

```
Private Sub CreateOneEachPerDP(DPNumber As Integer, OneEach As Powerpoint.Shape)


Dim Count As Integer
Dim NewShape As Powerpoint.Shape
Dim TopOfFirstShape As Integer
Dim SpaceBtwShapes As Integer

For Count = 0 To DPNumber

If Count = 0 Then ' position first shape
'create new shape = OneEach type
Set NewShape = OneEach
    With NewShape
        .Top = TopOfFirstShape
        .Left = 250
    End With
Else ' position further shapes
Set NewShape = OneEach.Duplicate ' GIVES AN ERROR OF TYPE MISMATCH - WHY?
    With NewShape
        .Top = TopOfFirstShape + (Count * SpaceBtwShapes)
        .Left = 250
    End With
End If
'need to size according to text
With NewShape
    .Width = 25
    .Height = 20
End With
'load shape with text (if necessary)
Next Count

pwEnd Sub
```

Comment: `Duplicate` returns type `ShapeRange`, not `Shape`, so you can't assign its return value to `NewShape`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code modification in the `Else` block (it takes the first and only shape from the Duplicated Range object):

```
Else ' position further shapes
    With OneEach.Duplicate(1)
        .Top = TopOfFirstShape + (Count * SpaceBtwShapes)
        .Left = 250
    End With
End If
```

Hope this will help.